# Transaction items are unintentionally shown as factor IDs using arules write() function

Tags: r, arules

I have a list of transactions in a .csv file. 
For each row, the first column contains a `"TransactionID"`. In the second columns contains the `"ItemName"` of a single item in that transaction. The third column contains the corresponding `"ItemNumber"`.

I import those transactions with `read.csv`.

```
trans = read.csv("MyFile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Then I take the relevant columns and convert them into a list with factors.

```
TransList <- split(trans[,"ItemNames"], trans[,"TransactionID"])
```

Finally I coerce this list to transactions.

```
TransMat <- as(TransList, "transactions")
```

Now I want to write the contents of each "basket" into a file.

```
write(TransMat, file = "Basket.csv", sep = ", ", quote = FALSE)
```

Unfortunately, instead of writing the original `"ItemNames"` into the file, the FactorIDs are written into the file.

What really confuses me, is the fact that this does not happen when I use the `"ItemNumbers"` instead of the `"ItemNames"`.

**How can I write the original "ItemNames" into a .csv file instead of the FactorIDs?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my own question.

Simply coercing to a data.frame before splitting did the trick.

```
trans <-as.data.frame(trans)
```

But honestly, I don't understand why this works... If anyone were to enlighten me in a comment I would greatly appreciate it.